# How to disable add button in yii2 wbraganca dynamic form?

Tags: forms, dynamic, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using **wbraganca** dynamic forms.I am setting the limit to 10, so only 10 forms can be added dynamically. Now I want to disable the add button when the limit of 10 forms is reached.

How can I do that ? please help anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through the documentation of wbraganca dynamic form.In there I have seen a JavaScript event gets called when the limit is reached.

```
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("limitReached", function(e, item) {
    alert("Limit reached");
});
```

Also I have seen the class used for insert button in the example given there is

```
'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class name given by default
```

So if you need to disable insert button when the limit is reached,the straight forward solution it seems is

```
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("limitReached", function(e, item) {

// I assume plugin doesn't disable button by default on reaching limit
        $(".add-item").prop('disabled', true);

    });
```

Source
[https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicforme](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform)